# How can we force AWS Lamda to run securely in a VPC?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

AWS Lamda execution can happen anywhere in the AWS cloud. Is there a way by which it can be forced to run in one VPC? How do we secure a Lamda function?

Comment: What does the Lambda function do? Does it access outside resources, such as Amazon S3 or resources in a VPC? From what are you wanting to 'secure' the Lambda function? Are you trying to control its outbound access? Feel free to Edit your Question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions always run in a VPC, but per default not in one of the VPCs you created in your account. To run them in a VPC in your account you have to provide VPC-configuration to your AWS Lambda function. AWS Lambda will use that configuration to set up an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) in the VPC which your AWS Lambda function then uses.

Here is an example from "[Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)" how to add such VPC configuration when creating an AWS Lambda function. Note the `vpc-config`-parameter:

```
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name ExampleFunction \
  --runtime go1.x \
  --role execution-role-arn \
  --zip-file fileb://path/app.zip \
  --handler app.handler \
  --vpc-config SubnetIds=comma-separated-vpc-subnet-ids,SecurityGroupIds=comma-separated-security-group-ids \
  --memory-size 1024
```

That said, please be aware of the downsides of running AWS Lambda functions in VPC, as explained in [Best Practices for Working with AWS Lambda Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html). As AWS sums it up:

> **Don't put your Lambda function in a VPC unless you have to.** There is no benefit outside of using this to access resources you cannot expose publicly, like a private [Amazon Relational Database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/) instance. Services like Amazon Elasticsearch Service can be secured over IAM with access policies, so exposing the endpoint publicly is safe and wouldn't require you to run your function in the VPC to secure it.

Comment: isn't this about accessing the VPC resources from Lamda? and not about running Lamda in a VPC?
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Comment: No, it's, as you asked, about running AWS Lambda functions in VPC. Although that's related to accessing resources in the VPC from AWS Lambda, as that is only possible if either these resources are publicly available on the internet or the AWS Lambda function runs in the VPC.